# Group by the parent in NDB query

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Say I've a model with School, Class, Student models.
In this model, classes are children of School, and students are children of class. What I'd like is to get all the students, grouped by their class.

Using NDB I can get call students for school A with:

```
school_key = ndb.Key( 'School', 'A' )
all_students_in_A = Student.query( ancestor = school_key ).fetch( )
```

However, I'd like to get the students in A groups by their class. Looking at the doc, query accepts a group_by argument, but only for actual fields of a model.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your question, but I felt I should raise it.  I wouldn't necessarily make student's a child of class -> school. this is a very rigid structure.  What happens when the student changes class.  The key of the student must change (which it can't) so know you have to create a new student entity representing the student in the new class.  Students should be child of a school (unless you want students to move between schools)  The student should have an enrolment record for the class or something similiar.

Comment: Thank you @Tim. You are correct. However, School/Class/Student was just an example. My actual product is an architecture firm web site, where I've Firm/Project/Image hierarchy, which is more static.

Comment: Something to note here is that group_by is similar to SQL's group by. The main purpose is for aggregation (in the case of the datastore, supporting SELECT DISTINCT). If you just want them all lined up next to each other, you could sort by \_\_key\_\_. Since a key is /ancestor1key/ancestor2key/key, all the students for each class would line up next to each other. However to actually put them in groups, you'd still have to post-process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using the python groupby function from itertools to post process and group entities.

Your selection needs to sort in the required order, in your case by key as your parents are in the key.

This approach will maintain the order.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

The code I have got is not easily shareable as the grouping function I have is part of a stored/authorable query entity which allows grouping by multiple attributes of the result items and the implementation is spread across a number of methods.  But shout out if you would like to see some code.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the grouping in Python after fetching the students.

```
classes = defaultdict(list)
for student in all_students_in_A:
    class = student.key.id()
    classes[class].append(student)
```

Now classes is a dict, where the keys are the class IDs and the values are lists of students.